# Entity mapping to DTO with DI with MapStruct

Tags: spring, mapstruct

I am new in mapstruct and I am using spring as DI I follow up MapStruct documentation page regarding DI containers section 4.2 I tried to map my entity to dto as below :

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface CustomerMapper {
@Mapping(source = "registered",target = "activeProfile")
CustomerDto customerToCustomerDto(Customer customer);
}
```

when i run mvn install i got this error :

```
java:27: error: No property named "registered" exists in source parameter(s).
@Mapping(source = "registered",target = "activeProfile")
```

my entity using lombok and I am sure there is registered field

please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed `lombok` from Entity and created setters /getters manually and worked well

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to to remove Lombok. 
You can setup it to work before MapStruct as was described here by **ahus1**
https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/510

```
<!-- first de-lombok the sources to make getters/setters visible for mapstruct,
but *DON'T'* add the output directory to the sources, as we will only need it for mapstruct processing -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${org.projectlombok.maven.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>delombok</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
                <addOutputDirectory>false</addOutputDirectory>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/delombok</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

<!-- use the de-lomobok files to create the necessary mappers -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <defaultOutputDirectory>
            ${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/mapstruct
        </defaultOutputDirectory>
        <processors>
            <processor>org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor</processor>
        </processors>
        <sourceDirectory>
            ${project.build.directory}/delombok
        </sourceDirectory>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>process</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>process</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

<!-- now take the original sources together with the created mappers to the compiler -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <annotationProcessors>
            <annotationProcessor>lombok.launch.AnnotationProcessorHider$AnnotationProcessor</annotationProcessor>
        </annotationProcessors>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Your workaround is not necessary anymore. Updating lombok to 1.16.14 should help. Take a look at link you posted

Answer (score 4):

I've solved the problem using annotationProcessors in pom.xml

```
   <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <annotationProcessorPaths>
                <path>
                   <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                   <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                   <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                </path>
                <path>
                   <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                   <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                   <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
                </path>
            </annotationProcessorPaths>
        </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Answer (score 2):

Neither you have to remove lombok from your project nor you have to mess up the maven compiler plugin. You just have to declare the lombok dependency before you declare the mapstruck dependency in your pom. With this order maven is able to de-lombok your classes, before mapstruct referes to the getters and setters. This is possibly a feature of maven's dependency mediation.

> Dependency mediation - this determines what version of a dependency
>   will be used when multiple versions of an artifact are encountered.
>   Currently, Maven 2.0 only supports using the "nearest definition"
>   which means that it will use the version of the closest dependency to
>   your project in the tree of dependencies. You can always guarantee a
>   version by declaring it explicitly in your project's POM. Note that if
>   two dependency versions are at the same depth in the dependency tree,
>   until Maven 2.0.8 it was not defined which one would win, but since
>   Maven 2.0.9 it's the order in the declaration that counts: the first
>   declaration wins.

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies

Answer (score 1):

The issue is, that Lombok generated properties are not visible to JSR-269 annotation processors. It uses internal api to modify the source elements directly instead of generating new artifacts from the annotated source files Therefore any annotation processor that relies on existence of getter/setter methods will not see them in the source code when it gets executed. Javac will pass the ,,original" source code to the annotation processor(in our case Mapstruct) without any modifications done by Lombok.

Right now the most clean solution how to get both of them working side-by-side is to move the Lombok annotated types and mappers into 2 separate projects. See an [official example in Mapstruct repo](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples/tree/master/mapstruct-lombok).